# Delphi Rest Callback Loginprompt

Tags: rest, delphi, callback

I have a callback in my application but when it gets a message it shows a login prompt for my REST Server.

Code:

```
FManager := TDSRestClientChannel.Create('ID', ChannelName,     DSRestConnection1);

  LCallback := TDSRestClientCallback.Create(Self.FManager, 'AnyName',
    function(AValue: TJSONValue; ADataType: string): Boolean
    begin
      TCallBackFunctions.QueueMessage(AValue.ToString);
      Result := true;
    end
  );
  FManager.RegisterCallback(LCallback);
```

I can't find anywhere with a LoginPrompt boolean or any method that calls for a login prompt.

Anyone has any idea on how to do that?

Comment: the login confirmation? it calls it before running the method

Comment: Hi Ricardo, if your comment is your answer, you should post it as an answr to your question

Comment: I want to remove the login prompt, as said it is already calling it...

Comment: this login prompt is accepting any username/password, it just shows up and, as long as I dont cancel, it works... but I dont want to show a random login prompt in my application everytime a callback is sent

Comment: Is your program a Web application, or a desktop EXE file?

Comment: its a multi-device application using firemonkey

Answer (score 0):

When your program displays the login prompt, pause your program in Delphi's debugger. Look at the call-stack window, and it will show exactly which functions were called to get you to that login dialog. Inspect the source code from there to determine how to avoid the dialog.

Comment: the call stack doesn't get there

Comment: it has nothing in it when it gets called

Comment: Did you remember to pause your program first? The debugger can't display anything about an actively running program.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that when you pause your program in the debugger, the call stack shows *nothing*. I don't know how else to help if your debugger is so crippled.

Comment: it's in a place called "RtlInitialization" or something like that. it doesn't get to any understandable code

Comment: Please try to be precise in your language. When you say "is has nothing," that doesn't agree with your later saying it includes `RtlInitialization` and other "CPU calls." The key point here is that somewhere, some code has generated a dialog box and is waiting for it to be destroyed before the program proceeds. Use the debugger to find that place. You might need to look in more than one thread. You're the one with the code, and you're the one operating the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In your component DSRestConnection1 there is a property LoginPrompt.

```
DSRestConnection1.LoginPrompt:= False;
```